# "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'validate' " error despite jquery.validate.js being include in the script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, mean-stack, typeerror

I am getting Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'validate', despite including  despite jquery.validate.js.
My page is part of a mean stack application.

This is the total set of scripts included :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script src="lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="js/formValidation.js"></script>
    <script>
    function validate()
{
    console.log("Entering");
jQuery(".form-inline").validate({
  rules: {
    "your-name": {
      required: true
    },
    "your-email": {
      required: true,
      email: true
    },
    "your-phone": {
      required: true
    },
    "your-checkin": {
      required: true
    },
    "your-checkout": {
      required: true
    },
  },
  messages: {
   "your-name": {
      required: "Please provide the required field",
      },
"your-email": {
      required: "Please provide the required field",
      email : "Please provide a valid email-ID"
      },
"your-phone": {
      required: "Please provide the required field",
      },
"your-checkin": {
      required: "Please provide the required field",
      }
  ,
  "your-checkout": {
      required: "Please provide the required field",
      }
  },
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    console.log(element);
    if (element.attr("name")=="your-name") {
      error.appendTo("#nameError");
    }
    else  if (element.attr("name")=="your-email") {
      error.appendTo("#emailError");
    }
    else  if (element.attr("name")=="your-phone") {
      error.appendTo("#phoneError");
    }
     if (element.attr("name")=="your-checkin") {
      error.appendTo("#checkinError");
    }
     if (element.attr("name")=="your-checkout") {
      error.appendTo("#checkoutError");
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
     getNotify();
  }
});
}
function getNotify(){
console.log(jQuery('form #Name').val());
  var deviceInfo = platform;
        var appointment = {
            inquirer: jQuery('form #Name').val(),
            email: jQuery('form #Email').val(),
            phone: jQuery('form #phone').val(),
            checkinDate: jQuery('form #date-picker-2').val(),
            checkinDate: jQuery('form #date-picker-3').val()
        };
 console.log(appointment);  
 jQuery.ajax({                
               type: "POST", 
               url: "http://aashish.digiapt.com/bookings", 
               crossDomain: true,       
               data: appointment,             
               dataType: "json",             
               success: function( response )          
               {                           
                console.log("response with:",response);           
               },              
    error: function( error )          
    {                
    console.log( "ERROR:", error );      
          },          
      complete: function()          
      {        
 jQuery('#Message-success-label').show();
jQuery('#Message-success-label').fadeOut(8000);
jQuery('form #Name').val('');
 jQuery('form #Email').val('');
jQuery('form #phone').val('');
jQuery('form #date-picker-2').val('');  
          jQuery('form #date-picker-3').val('');
  console.log("done");             
    }          
  }); 
}</script>
```

As you can I have included the  tag. But still I get the  error :
despite jquery.validate.js

Comment: Why are you putting the `.validate()` method inside of a function called `validate()`?  Simply put the `.validate()` method inside of a DOM ready event handler.

Comment: Is so much easier and cleaner to validate forms with angular, this is a good read http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/validations.html